# Unable to use the same resource in two different Canvases

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, dll, user-controls

I have an application with two Canvas controls. When the application starts, it loads from a DLL  a UserControl which is basically Canvas with a bunch of XAML code.

I want to be able to display this control in the two Canvases, however, when I use the ContentPresenter and bind it in both Canvases to the control loaded from the DLL it shows only on one canvas and on the other it doesn't. I guess it's something that has to do with the fact that I'm actually using the **same** resource in two different Canvases, but since I wanted to avoid using too much memory (the control loaded from the DLL is pretty heavy) I didn't want to create two copies of the same control.

Does anyone have a better approach / solution for this situation?

This is the XAML for showing the loaded control in one of the two canvases (the other canvas uses similar code)

```
<Canvas Width="{Binding MapModel.MapControl.Bounds.Width}" Height="{Binding MapModel.MapControl.Bounds.Height}">
    <Canvas.Background>
         <VisualBrush>
             <VisualBrush.Visual>
                  <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding MapModel.MapControl}" />
             </VisualBrush.Visual>
         </VisualBrush>
    </Canvas.Background>
 </Canvas>
```

And loading from the DLL is performed by:

```
  // Load the map library assembly (Using reflection)
  Assembly asm = Assembly.LoadFile(m_fileName);
  Type[] tlist = asm.GetTypes();

  // Find the class that represents the airport XAML drawing in the assembly, if it finds the airport class then 
  // set the value to be an instance of that class.
  foreach (Type t in tlist)
  {
    if (t.Name == "Map")
    {
      MapControl = Activator.CreateInstance(t) as UserControl;
      break;
    }
  }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you show us some code? i know this problem just with images.

Comment: I've edited the post and posted some code, thanks!

Comment: Is MapControl static? What class is loading the assembly? Are you sure you have created 2 instances?

Comment: Karel, MapControl isn't static. Also, the issue here is that I don't want to create two instances of MapControl, but I want to create one instance and use it twice in two Canvases (using ContentPresenter to display the control). The class loading the assembly is MapModel class which serves as a model in the MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set attribute [`x:Shared`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx)`="False"` to your resource.
It is `'true'` so wpf creates one resource (for optimize performance) by default. When you set it `'false'` wpf creates new instance per request.
[There are sample of this](http://rredcat.blogspot.com/2009/02/trips-do-you-know-how-you-can-extract.html)